# Meteor pub sub same collection different projection

Tags: node.js, mongodb, reactjs, meteor

i have been working in a project recently with Meteor and React, and i have some issues with Meteor publish and subscribe.

Here is the example code:

this is the first publication that i have and when the user goes to the page `settings/notifications' we can see the notifications settings

```
# Publish user notifications settings information 

import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor'
import Users      from '../../users.coffee'

Meteor.publish 'user.notifications.settings', ->

If not @userId then throw new Meteor.Error 403, 'You must be logged in.'

fields = {}

fields["settings.notifications"] = on


Users.find( { _id : @userId } , { fields } )
```

this one is the second publication when the user goes to the page `settings/api` it shows the API settings

```
# Publish user API-keys

EXCHANGES = require '../../../../startup/both/exchanges'

import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor'
import Users      from '../../users.coffee'

Meteor.publish 'user.api_keys', ( user_id ) ->

# return ready if no use_id is passed
return @ready() if not user_id

fields = {}

for exchange in EXCHANGES

  if user_id is @userId
    fields["settings.exchanges.#{exchange}"] = on
  else
    fields["settings.exchanges.#{exchange}.valid"] = on


Users.find( { _id : user_id }, { fields } )
```

the problem here is when the user navigates from one page to another Meteor doesn't update the subscription

on my component, i have this subscription

```
Meteor.subscribe 'user.notifications.settings'
```

and on the other one

```
Meteor.subscribe 'user.api_keys', user_id
```

if i console.log 
    Users.find()
It shows the projection of the previous publications and not the current projection if i refresh the page it shows the right one. Only when i navigate from one route to another, the error comes.

thanks

Comment: Are you using withTracker?

Comment: Yes I'm using withtracker